# Angular 7 Http Get returning '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, http, observable, angular7

I have a service who call an API with the following function:

```
getAll(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this.http.get<Client[]>(`${this.url}/clients`) 
}
```

And in my component the service call :

```
  getClients() {
      this.clientService.getAll().subscribe(
      res => {
         this.clients = res;
         console.log(this.clients);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
);}
```

With this, I get a response object of objects. My API is returning an Array of objects, but someway the Observable function transforms the data in an object of objects with numeric indices:
[Console img with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6EcC.png)

anyone knows what's the problem?

## Solution:

Using KeyValue Pipe is a workaround like commented by @Suryan.
The problem was a sort method in my API, which changed the array into an object.  It's not necessary to use pipe or map in service, as well not necessary use pipe keyvalue. @Suryan [make an example demonstrating this point](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-api-response?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Are you using HttpClient? if not then you need `res.data`

Comment: import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Yes, I using HttpCliente. With res.data I get the following error:
error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Client[]'.

Comment: Try look into the network tab, are you getting the correct response as you said "My Api is returning an Array of objects"

Comment: @Suryan My API return is correct. The problem is in Angular.  Request the API with Angular 6 version works fine. The problem is only when I update the Angular version for 7.

Comment: Don't mind but I think this is just the work around not the solution and what you are trying to say is framework is the problem

Comment: Here is the working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-api-response?file=src/app/app.component.html framework is not the problem

Comment: Make sense man! I will try some tests on my API. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using KeyValue Pipe will solve the problem

```
<div *ngFor="let item of clients | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{item.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{item.value}}</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Man! you are a lifesaver hehehe
it works like a charm!  thanks!

Comment: @ThiagoReis but the question still remains as you said "My Api is returning an Array of objects"

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
this.clients = res.data;
```

Comment: With res.data I get the following error:
error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Client[]'.

Answer (score -2):

Try making the following changes in your .service.ts file

```
getAll(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this.http.get<Client[]>(`${this.url}/clients`).map(res=>res.json()); 
}
```

Comment: HttpClient.get() applies res.json() automatically and returns Observable<HttpResponse<string>>. You no longer need to call this function yourself.